# Angular HttpRequest cannot set class field to my data values

Tags: angular, http

I have a problem with Angular and its HttpRequest,
I want to get some data with HttpRequest get method, here is my code:

```
getChartsData() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:5555/DNZ/Produkt/Monat/by/12')
    .subscribe((res: Response) => {
      this.chartData = res.json() as chartData[];
      this.formatData(this.chartData);
      console.log("Chart Data: ", this.chartData);

    });
  }
```

However, I am not able to save my json  data in the chartData field, to use it later, because I want to format my data first so that I can use them in NGXCharts...? in the NgOnit() method, I try to call the data by the method and then log the data to console:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getChartsData();
    console.log("Init data:" , this.chartData);        
  }

constructor(private http: Http) {
    Object.assign(this, { chart })
    this.chartData = this.getChartsData();
  }
```

but here chartData is undefined...

I am quite new to Angular, maybe I am just confusing code exection order or something, I guess there is an error in my logic somewhere..?

Comment: You need to understand asynchronism. The code inside the callback passed to subscribe() is executed asynchronously, when the server response has come back, wayyyy after the ngOnInit method has returned. You also need to stop using the old Http service, which is deprecated since Angular 4.3, in favor of HttpClient.

Comment: JB Nizet is right.One way would be to make ChartData() return an Observable<YourChartDataType> and pass this to the chart, so the chart will have the data as soon as the http call has been finished. You can have a look here how Angular works with Obversvables https://angular.io/guide/rx-library

Comment: sorry I cannot make out how I'd have to modify my app so that it fits the new HttpClient Module.. its kind of confusing..